# Filter Array object by title key

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to get each data by filtering 'page_title' key.
This is my sample json object.

```
{
"page_components": [
  {
    "page_title": "My Account",
    "row_block": [
      {
        "heading": "",
        "sub_heading": "We have been busy creating a place where you can find all your favorite saved products and access our brand new tools.",
        "header_image": {
          "title": "Home-Loans-Sushi-Train",
          "filename": "Home-Loans-Sushi-Train.png",
          "url": "Home-Loans-Sushi-Train.png"
        },
        "show_gold_icon_list": false,
        "show_blue_icon_list": false,
        "show_cta_button": false
      },
      {
        "heading": "Start comparing and saving",
        "sub_heading": "",
        "header_image": {
          "title": "gold_logo",
          "filename": "gold_logo.png",
          "url": "gold_logo.png"
        },
        "show_gold_icon_list": true,
        "show_blue_icon_list": false,
        "show_cta_button": true,
        "cta_button_text": "Compare",
        "cta_button_color": "#008390",
        "cta_button_link": ""
      },
      {
        "heading": "Start comparing and saving using Blue",
        "sub_heading": "",
        "header_image": {
          "title": "blue_logo",
          "filename": "blue_logo.png",
          "url": "blue_logo.png"
        },
        "show_gold_icon_list": false,
        "show_blue_icon_list": true,
        "show_cta_button": true,
        "cta_button_text": "Compare with Blue",
        "cta_button_color": "#008390",
        "cta_button_link": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "page_title": "Saved Products",
    "row_block": [
      {
        "heading": "You donâ€™t have any saved products",
        "sub_heading": "Save products that youâ€™re interested in from the comparison table and find them here later.",
        "header_image": {
          "title": "gold_logo",
          "filename": "gold_logo.png",
          "url": "gold_logo.png"
        },
        "show_gold_icon_list": true,
        "show_blue_icon_list": false,
        "show_cta_button": true,
        "cta_button_text": "Compare",
        "cta_button_color": "#008390",
        "cta_button_link": ""
      },
      {
        "heading": "Saved products coming soon to Blue ",
        "sub_heading": "",
        "header_image": {
          "title": "blue_logo",
          "filename": "blue_logo.png",
          "url": ""
        },
        "show_gold_icon_list": false,
        "show_blue_icon_list": false,
        "show_cta_button": true,
        "cta_button_text": "Compare with Blue",
        "cta_button_color": "#087DB2",
        "cta_button_link": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "page_title": "Saved Shortlists",
    "row_block": [
      {
        "heading": "You donâ€™t have any saved shortlists with",
        "sub_heading": "Save made by doing a three way comparison and find them here later.",
        "header_image": {
          "title": "gold_logo",
          "filename": "gold_logo.png",
          "url": ""
        },
        "show_gold_icon_list": true,
        "show_blue_icon_list": false,
        "show_cta_button": true,
        "cta_button_text": "Compare",
        "cta_button_color": "#008390",
        "cta_button_link": ""
      },
      {
        "heading": "Saved shortlists coming soon",
        "sub_heading": "",
        "header_image": {
          "title": "blue_logo",
          "filename": "blue_logo.png",
          "url": ""
        },
        "show_gold_icon_list": false,
        "show_blue_icon_list": false,
        "show_cta_button": true,
        "cta_button_text": "Compare with Blue",
        "cta_button_color": "#087DB2",
        "cta_button_link": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

I want to get each row_block by filtering page_title. Currently i have this code and it seems not working. I was confused how to get each row_block given title is being passed through the function.

```
getPageComponents(title: string) {
 this.pageComponents.filter((page) => {
   return page.page_title === title;
 });
}
```

But it i was unable to get the result. Can somebody help me using filter in javascript. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with TypeScript, but it shouldn't matter... `.filter` does not act on the array... it returns a new array. Try setting something equal to `this.pageComponents.filter` or returning it.

Comment: did you check title parameter data
?

Comment: you are missing `return` keyword

Comment: @MdMahamudulHasan yes i've already checked it.

Comment: @Phong I've added return keyword still not working

Comment: You mean it returns all?

Comment: @Phong Omg. I think it is working now. Big help!!! It was awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `return` keyword

```
getPageComponents(title: string) {
 return  this.pageComponents.filter((page) => {
   return page.page_title === title;
 });
}
```